# How to deal with Linux error: for 'ping', 'cannot execute binary file'

Tags: linux, error-handling

```
/home/$USER/bin/ping: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux $USER 5.13.0-22-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 5 13:21:36 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Ping reinstall does not help.

Comment: what if you run `/usr/bin/ping`? also, what does `file /home/$USER/bin/ping` output

Comment: .. Given that `ping` needs to be SUID root for the privileges required to form ICMP packets, I am *extremely* concerned about a custom version of ping in your `$PATH`

Comment: It does not need to be `setuid`, it can use `capabilities`. Certainly on opensuse, it is not `setuid`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you have a custom `ping` installed to your `~/bin/` which takes precedence in your `$PATH`. The actual, system-wide ping is located at `/usr/bin/ping` (at least on Ubuntu 21.04 Hirsute Hippo). As Bravo pointed it out, you may check what's going on with your ping with the `file` command. (Most likely it will turn out it's for different architecture, damaged, or not even a binary.)